# Para que serve a função join() no módulo threading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, join, multithreading

Já vi a função `join()` para o módulo `threading`, mas não entendi direito o que ela faz.

Answer (score 9):

O `.join` simplesmente pausa a thread atual (de onde ele foi chamado) até que a thread alvo (a thread a que ele está atrelado) termine.

É uma forma de voltar a sincronizar o programa, garantindo que não estejam ocorrendo processamentos em paralelo.

O que ele *não* faz é o mais importante: ele não transmite nenhum sinal, faz qualquer pedido, ou faz com a thread alvo seja encerrada.  O programa continua correndo normalmente, a thread alvo continua seu processamento - e, quando ela for encerrada, a função join retorna.

Em outras palavras, a chamada `minhathread.join()` é o equivalente a "pause o programa aqui e espere que a minhathread termine".

Se você precisar de uma forma de avisar outra thread que ela deve terminar, tem que dar uma olhada nos eventos de thread e nas queues - e seu código que roda na thread tem que olhar essas mensagens e encerrar a execução. Em Python não há uma forma de um sinal externo encerrar uma thread em execução, sem que o código dela preveja isso. (em outras linguagens também não há uma forma segura de fazer isso, apenas "paradas violentas")

O método join também aceita um parâmetro de timeout em segundos: é o tempo máximo que a execução vai esperar o encerramento da outra thread - depois desse tempo a chamada retorna, e você tem que verificar se a thread alvo ainda está ativa chamando o método `.is_alive` dela.

Abaixo, faço uma brincadeira com duas threads numa sessão interativa, e demonstro o uso de um objeto "threading.Event" para parar uma thread, e do "join" numa segunda thread que espera o final da primeira:

```py
In [227]: import threading        

In [228]: evento = threading.Event()                                 

In [229]: def contador(): 
     ...:     i = 0 
     ...:     while True: 
     ...:         parar_agora = evento.wait(1) 
     ...:         if parar_agora: 
     ...:             break 
     ...:         i += 1 
     ...:         print(i) 
     ...:                         

In [230]: def espera_contador(t): 
     ...:     t.join() 
     ...:     print("O contador parou") 
     ...:                         

In [231]: t1 = threading.Thread(target=contador); t2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: espera_contador(t1))                               

In [232]: t1.start(); t2.start() 
     ...:                         

1
2
3
4
5
6
In [233]: evento.set()            

O contador parou
```

(O uso do lambda em `lambda: espera_contador(t1)` foi feito para passar o parâmetro "t1" para a chamada, já que "target" não aceita parâmetros - depois me lembrei que poderia ter usado o parâmetro "args" ao criar a thread: `t1 = threading.Thread(target=contador); t2 = threading.Thread(target=espera_contador, args=[t1])`)

Comment: Obrigado,valeu pela explicação.

Comment: Lembrando que deve-se chamar join() para todas as threads, mesmo que já tenham parado. O fato de chamar join() libera recursos de sistema, de forma semelhante ao wait() para processos. Uma thread é um "processo leve" e o sistema armazena seu estado até que alguém chame join() ler esse estado.

Comment: sim - se for se desenhar uma app de longa duração que use threads, com implementaçao em baixo nível usando `threading`, precisa. Acho que 90% do que se escreve usando threading são scripts "one shot" - acabou, encerra o processo (aí é bom o join pra garantir que tudo foi finalizado). Outros usos encapsulam as criações de threads e sinalizações entre elas em construções de mais alto nível (ex. concurrent.futures) .